# Paintbrush Effect in using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope that this finds everyone well.

In the following example, I was wondering if the paintbrush effect, writing *kygo* is feasible to do with css and HTML alone, and if not, would I be able to do this using javascript?

Example for reference:

https://dribbble.com/shots/4221064-Kygo-Landing-Concept

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It may be possible in CSS, but it would be a massive amount of work. It may also be possible in JS/SVG, but again, would be a lot of work. The easiest way, by far, would be to render the effect in a video and put that in the background of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose a proper font (for example [this](https://www.fontspace.com/magic-brush-font-f83151)) and add a blueish green gradient with CSS, then reveal the letters as they were painted with a clipping mask combined with CSS animation.

Here's the first step:

```css
@import url('http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/magic-brush');
#kygo {
  font-family: 'Magic Brush', sans-serif;
  font-size: 250px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #a5f9b3, #66deef);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: 3s reveal-text;
}

@keyframes reveal-text {
  0% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 10% 0, 10% 0, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 10% 0, 10% 0, 0 0);
  }
100% {
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 10% 100%, 10% 0, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 10% 100%, 10% 0, 0 0);
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="kygo">KYGO</div>
```